# How this error occure

Tags: java, class

Hi all I have following code that generates error why.If any know please suggest me.

```
public class Class {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        public int i = 10;
        i = i++;
        System.out.println("Value of i=" + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Next time put the error you're getting.

Comment: Your description is vague - you don't tell us what the error is and on which line it occurs. In this specific case the error was obvious. However, please include the relevant information in your future posts. Help yourself to get useful answers.

Comment: 1. it doesn't compile because of the wrong use of the `public` keyword. 2. If you remove `public` it will print 10 when you probably expect 11. Replace `i = i++;` by just `i++;`

Comment: Yeah u r right assylias, but i want to know when we using public then why its generates error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a visibility modifier, `public`, for a local variable. This isn't allowed (and makes no sense) since the scope of a local variable is always confined to within that method.

The following code:

```
public class Class {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 10;
        i = i++;
        System.out.println("Value of i=" + i);
    }
}
```

...compiles no problem.

Note you could also potentially move the `i` outside the method to a field, which would also work:

```
public class Class {

    public int i = 10;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        i = i++;
        System.out.println("Value of i=" + i);
    }
}
```

Note that `i = i++` may also be causing an issue different to what you're expecting, but it's difficult to say without a more thorough explanation. You probably just meant `i++` on that line.

Comment: `i = i++` might be an error too.

Answer (score 3):

because you can't specify the access specifier on local variables

```
public int i = 10;
```

make it

```
int i = 10;
```

Also as [assylias commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598676/how-this-error-occure/10598697#comment13729097_10598697) , It won't make any effect on the the assignment if you do `i = i++;`

Answer (score 1):

'i' is a local variable. It cannot be public / private / protected.
You can although mark it as final.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be defining i as "int i = 10" and not "public int" as it's not a class variable

Answer (score 0):

The error is that `public` can't be applied to local variables. Change:

```
public int i = 10;
```

to

```
int i = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a local variable to the `main` method. Local variables do not have scopes `public, private, protected`. Only field members can have them. So remove the `public` modifier in front of the `i` variable.

Answer (score 0):

**public int i = 10;** // *This will populate error*

you can't declare local variable with scope like `public or private`

Change it to `int i=10;` It'll work.

Thanks